# React functional component default parameters

Tags: reactjs

I'm creating a function component called `ExecutionsComponent` that takes 3 parameters (called doc, start, end). I've defined these parameters in the interface `ExecutionsComponentProps`. Since start and end are optional, I want to set a default value for these two parameters. I've done that as follows:

```
interface ExecutionsComponentProps {
  doc: any;
  start?: string;
  end?: string;
}

export default function ExecutionsComponent({
  start = DateTime.now().minus({ weeks: 1 }).toISODate(),
  end = DateTime.now().toISODate(),
}: ExecutionsComponentProps) {

   // Component code
   // How do I now reference the doc value?
   // console.log(doc) would error out

}
```

The question I now have is, how do I reference the `doc` value within my component? If I'd for example write down `console.log(doc)` I'd get:

> ReferenceError: habitDoc is not defined

Comment: Just add `doc` in the rest parameter list along with `start` and `end` but with no default value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've just missed adding it as a prop.

```
interface ExecutionsComponentProps {
  doc: any
  start?: string
  end?: string
}

export default function ExecutionsComponent({
  doc, // <- you missed this
  start = DateTime.now().minus({ weeks: 1 }).toISODate(),
  end = DateTime.now().toISODate(),
}: ExecutionsComponentProps) {
  console.log(doc);
}
```